# What are DIRS and APP_DIRS in django ? and what is it use for?

Tags: django

I am making a django app and when I was reading about template loaders I saw this:

You can enable this loader simply by setting `APP_DIRS` to `True`:

```
TEMPLATES = [{
'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
'APP_DIRS': True,
}]
```

what is this doing ? and what are the uses of DIRS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DIR is stand for direction which is allow you to read directory files and use it in your django project.
for example look at this line of code :

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

it allow you too read all files in templates folder in your directory and render your templates like yourHTMLfile.html or others and also it could have multiple value.